# Why do we use Hoeffding inequality in UCB approach to drive the confidence set in multi-armed bandit problem?

Tags: lg.learning, online-learning

In UCB algorithm, to drive the confidence set for unknown parameters we use Hoeffding inequality. I am wondering why we don't use Normal distribution instead which is much simpler to work with. Based on the central limit theorem, when the sample size increases, we can approximate the sample mean distribution with Normal distribution. So, it won't have much error using this approximation.

Thanks

Comment: What is the UCB algorithm?

Comment: Upper confidence bound in multi-armed bandit problem.

Comment: @katan could you post a reference or a place where it is used?

Comment: Because it's not necessary to assume that the reward distribution for each arm is normal?